# How to detect if application quick settings tile is added

Tags: java, android

I followed this tutorial to build a QuickSettings Tile: 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-n-quick-settings/#0

All good so far, but now I'm stuck on this:

How can i detect (inside an Activity) if the tile is currently added?

My first attempt was to store this in a file (using `onTileAdded` and `onTileRemoved`), but that may get out of sync (either "Data Clear" or user editing if using the external storage).

Is there a safe way I can get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a static variable in the Service:

```
public class MyTileService extends TileService {
    public static boolean isAdded = false;

    //...

    @Override
    public void onTileAdded() {
        isAdded = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTileRemoved() {
        isAdded = false;
    }
}
```

Then just access that variable from your Activity.

Unfortunately, since TileServices already override `onBind()` you can't use a Binder to get the value on demand. As an alternative to a static variable, consider using the LocalBroadcastManager to send a broadcast from the TileService when it's added or removed. Then you can receive the result in your Activity and use it to update a global variable there.